# when adding a <p> tag to div element, margin becomes 1/2 of parent div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align a row of - icon |text| - icon |text| - icon |text|
It seems okay when just having the div's next to eachother and they seem to align proper as well. But when I add a

tag between the child div, it behaves really weird and set's its margin to 1/2 of the parent div.

This is what my HTML looks like:

```
<section id="subber">
            <span class="subber-element-icon">
            </span>
            <div class="subber-element">
                <p>hafjadljla;j kfaj lfjadklj;af kl;aj a</p>
            </div>
</section>
```

And this is whay the CSS looks like:

```
#subber {
height: 10%;
width: 100%;
}

.subber-element{
height: 100%;
display: inline-block;
border: 1px black solid;
width: 30%;
}

.subber-element p{
font-family: vegur regular;
color: grey;
display: inline;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.subber-element-icon{
height: 100%;
width: 10%;
border: 1px black solid;
display: inline-block;   
}
```

Hopefully one of you guys can help out!

Comment: you  have margin:0 1em; set by default to <p> (as hX). reset it's margin to 0 or whatever you wish :) if parent has no borders nor padding, <p> margin jumps out the box (this is default behavior). Set a padding or a border to your <div> if you want to keep margin inside.)

Comment: I'm sorry, not working :( I've set everything to 0 now (including the default settings) and it behaves the same :(

Comment: Sorry, padding or borders in div should have a 0+X value.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by 0+X? 0+X still makes X so I can't see how that should become zero?

Comment: i mean 1px to whatever. Just tested your code and , indeed you have a funny behavior. set div to display:inline and it should work. I have no explanation though for that. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tBDhd

Comment: What is the problem in particular? I don't understand.. You want an alignment of section in vertical or horizontal? You have a problem in the space between icon and text?

Comment: I want it to align with 0px or whatever to the left element with the text in the element, but it doensn't seem to work..

Comment: Like here? http://jsfiddle.net/hVfS4/

Comment: I'm sorry GCyrillus, but that doesn't work with a larger size div. As you can see it isn't completely sticked to the top..

Comment: nice Riccardo! Thanks for this quick solve :) great solution and i'll give it a max width to make it stick to the center on larger screens :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll post the solution also here with [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hVfS4)

HTML

```
<div id="subber">
        <img class="icon">
        </img>
        <section class="text">
              <p>PROVA PROVA PROVA CON DEL TESTO</p>
        </section>
  </div>
  <div id="subber">
        <div class="icon">
        </div>
        <section class="text">
            <p><span>PROVA PROVA PROVA CON DEL TESTO TESTO TESTO</span></p>
        </section>
  </div>
  <div id="subber">
        <div class="icon">
        </div>
        <section class="text">
            <p>PROVA PROVA PROVA CON DEL TESTO TESTO TESTO</p>
        </section>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.icon{
height:50px;
width:50px;
border:1px solid black;
float:left;
}
.text{
border:1px solid black;
float:left;
height:50px;
max-width:300px;
color:red;
}
.text p{
height:50px;
padding:0px;
}

#subber{
float:left;
width:400px;
height:50px;
}
```